# Create Multidimensional Zeros Python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, numpy

I need to make a multidimensional array of zeros.

For two (D=2) or three (D=3) dimensions, this is easy and I'd use:

```
a = numpy.zeros(shape=(n,n))
```

or

```
a = numpy.zeros(shape=(n,n,n))
```

How for I for higher D, make the array of length n?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can multiply a tuple `(n,)` by the number of dimensions you want.  e.g.:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> N=2
>>> np.zeros((N,)*1)
array([ 0.,  0.])
>>> np.zeros((N,)*2)
array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.]])
>>> np.zeros((N,)*3)
array([[[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]]])
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> sh = (10, 10, 10, 10)
>>> z1 = zeros(10000).reshape(*sh)
>>> z1.shape
(10, 10, 10, 10)
```

EDIT: while above is not wrong, it's just excessive. @mgilson's answer is better.

Comment: On second thought, I'm not really sure how this gets you anything that `np.zeros` doesn't already support.  How is this better than `np.zeros(sh)`?

Comment: @mgilson: you're right. No need for extra brackets, as well: `np.zeros(sh)`  works.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant :)

Answer (score 3):

```
In [4]: import numpy

In [5]: n = 2

In [6]: d = 4

In [7]: a = numpy.zeros(shape=[n]*d)

In [8]: a
Out[8]: 
array([[[[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]]],


       [[[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]]]])
```

Comment: This really isn't any different than my answer other than you're using a list rather than a tuple ...

Answer (score 1):

you can make multidimensional array of zeros by using square brackets

```
array_4D = np.zeros([3,3,3,3])
```