# How can I create an empty 3d multidimensional array

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, list-comparison

This code is my attempt at creating an empty 3d array.

```
n=3
board = [[[ 0 for _ in range(n)]
            for _ in range(n)]
            for _ in range(n)]
print(board)
```

So, what that creates is exactly what I'm looking for a 3d array with dimensions n by n by n, but the list is filled with 0's and if I take out the 0 an error occurs. How would I create this same list but empty?

Comment: My eyes hurt...

Comment: What exactly is the format of sample output you are are looking for? My best guess is you want `[[ [] for _ in range(n)]
            for _ in range(n)]`

Comment: You can't do that. Python doesn't work that way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Multidimensional Zeros Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393216/create-multidimensional-zeros-python)

Comment: What do you think an empty list of length `n` looks like?

Comment: A list with a unicorn in it ?

Comment: `board = [[[0] * n] * n] * n`

Comment: @JohnGordon: It wont't create new list, But nested lists with same references

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `[]` instead of `0` as:

```
n = 5
empty_list = [[[ [] for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
```

Value hold by `empty_list` will be:

```
[[[[], [], [], [], []], 
  [[], [], [], [], []], 
  [[], [], [], [], []], 
  [[], [], [], [], []], 
  [[], [], [], [], []]], 
# Repeated 4 more times
```

For example:

```
>>> empty_list[0][0][0]  # Access element with nest level 3 in list
[]
```

Comment: if i was to try and access empty_list[0][0][0] it would be out of range right. I am looking for something exactly as you have done above but where that index to the third degree is accessible

Comment: I think in the above post you have created a 2d list with just extra brackets inside of it as oppose to a 3d list

Comment: Is this not a 3d list with brackets inside of it?

Comment: As per my definition of 3D; the solution I mentioned earlier was a 3D list. It is a 4D list. OR, in other words you may say 3D list with value as *empty lists*

Comment: If i wanted to print this in the format shown above, where every 2d list has its own line, how would i do it?

Comment: In that case, it should be a different question as it related to formatting and not related to the question you originally asked. Just to give you the idea. It is a Python's data-structure. In case you want to change the format you need to display; you have to convert it to string and format it